# Parse single message coming over socket containing 2 strings in C

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

I'm trying to read a message that contains 2 strings. This message contains 2 strings that could be anything, and it is sent over a socket.

Note that I'm using C in Ubuntu environment.

The format of the message is, in a single `void* buffer`:

`[string1]\0[string2]\0`

I figured I'd be able to separate them once they arrive, using the '\0' to figure out where to split them. I'm using a function to read just the string and it sort of works, but I keep getting complaints from Valgrind, and I don't understand why.

I'm going to use an example where only 1 string is read from the buffer, but I mention the strategy because I'm not able to just put the message into a `char* buffer`. I need the function to extract a string from more complex buffers.

It all starts like this:

```
void* buffer = malloc(msgSize * sizeof(char)); //the message size is properly calculated to include the '\0' at the end
char* instanceId = malloc(msgSize * sizeof(char));

if(recv(socket_desc, (void*) buffer, msgSize * sizeof(char), MSG_WAITALL) <= 0) {
        log_error(logger, "Message failed.");
        return;
    }

    bufferToString(buffer, &instanceId, 0);
    bufferToString2(buffer, instanceId, 0);
```

I made several attempts to make bufferToString work, as you can see... Of course I don't invoke them all at the same time, but I want to share those lines in case I'm making a mistake there.

**Attempt #Number 1: char by char**

```
int bufferToString(void* buffer, char** string, int startPtr) {
    //startPtr can be used to read strings that are in the middle of a buffer
    char a;
    int thisStringPtr = 0; 

    do {
        a = *(char*) (buffer + startPtr);
        (*string)[thisStringPtr] = a;
        startPtr++;
        thisStringPtr++;
    } while (a != '\0');
    return startPtr; //return end position to use for extracting more values later
```

}

This one complains:

```
==23047== Invalid read of size 1
==23047==    at 0x403A27A: bufferToString (buffer.c:16)
==23047==    by 0x804A0C2: handleHiloInstancia (coordinador.c:232)
==23047==    by 0x8049C54: procesarConexion (coordinador.c:85)
==23047==    by 0x4066294: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==23047==    by 0x41650AD: clone (clone.S:114)
==23047==  Address 0x423bc8a is 0 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23047==    at 0x402C17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==23047==    by 0x804A063: handleHiloInstancia (coordinador.c:225)
==23047==    by 0x8049C54: procesarConexion (coordinador.c:85)
==23047==    by 0x4066294: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==23047==    by 0x41650AD: clone (clone.S:114)
```

Line 16 of bufferToString is the first line inside the `do` statement.

**Attempt 2: cast and copy**

```
int bufferToString2(void* buffer, char* string, int startPtr) {
    strcpy(string, (char*) (buffer + startPtr));
    return (strlen(string) + 1)*sizeof(char);
}
```

With or without the +startPtr, this causes slightly different problems:

```
==23190== Invalid read of size 1
==23190==    at 0x402F489: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==23190==    by 0x403A1E3: bufferToString2 (buffer.c:3)
==23190==    by 0x804A0C1: handleHiloInstancia (coordinador.c:232)
==23190==    by 0x8049C54: procesarConexion (coordinador.c:85)
==23190==    by 0x4066294: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==23190==    by 0x41650AD: clone (clone.S:114)
==23190==  Address 0x423bc8a is 0 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
```

I tried a few other combinations (like using char** string and all the required modifications in bufferToString2), but I keep getting similar error messages. What am I not seeing?

UPDATE: How message is being sent:

```
    int bufferSize;
    void* buffer = serializePackage(HANDSHAKE_INSTANCE_ID ,instancia_config->nombre, &bufferSize );
    printf("Buffer size: %i - Instancia Name = %s - Socket num: %i\n", bufferSize, instancia_config->nombre, socket_coordinador); //this shows right data
    if (send(socket_coordinador,buffer,bufferSize, 0) <= 0) {
        log_error(logger, "Could not send ID.");
        endProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

instancia_config->nombre is of type char*

```
void* serializePackage(int codigo,char * mensaje, int* tamanioPaquete){

    int puntero = 0;
    int length = strlen(mensaje);

    int sizeOfPaquete = strlen(mensaje) * sizeof(char) + 1 + 2 * sizeof(int);
    void * paquete = malloc(sizeOfPaquete);


    memcpy((paquete + puntero) ,&codigo,sizeof(int));
    puntero += sizeof(int);

    memcpy((paquete + puntero),&length,sizeof(int));
    puntero += sizeof(int);

    memcpy((paquete + puntero),mensaje,length * sizeof(char) + 1);

    *tamanioPaquete = sizeOfPaquete;
    return paquete;

}
```

Comment: This one look suspicious: *//the message size is properly calculated to include the '\0' at the end*. Usually when people say that, it is not true.

Comment: By the way, `buffer + startPtr` is invalid in standard C, as it does not allow pointer arithmetic on `void*`.

Comment: Posting how data was sent is useful to add clarity in how to receive it.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, @EugeneSh. The error message moved to line 20 ((*string)[thisStringPtr] = a;. I had accidentally removed that line from the code I pasted before, so it might be a big part of the problem...

Comment: Thought 1: I would drop `* sizeof(char)` everywhere you're using it. The `sizeof` a `char` in C is 1 by definition. So that just clutters your code.

Comment: Thought 2: You should never, never, never trust that a buffer you received over the network contains a certain character (like a null). That's a recipe for creating a buffer overrun security vulnerability. Instead, either pass the expected length to `bufferToString` and ensure that function doesn't go beyond the length. Or simply force a null at the end of the buffer immediately after the `recv` to ensure the terminator will be found: `((char *)buffer)[msgSize - 1] = '\0';`

Comment: The message you receiver would the first thing I would suspect: Have the message dumped to stdout right after reception and check that it actually contains a zero byte. If you don't know how to handle a Debugger (you should learn!), this should do as well: ` char* msg = buffer; for(size_t i = 0; i < msgSize; ++i) printf("%c", msg[i]); printf("###\n");` BTW: Usw appropriate data types, e.g. `size_t` for non-negative sizes. Why do you Hand over the `string` as `char**`? Whats wrong sich a simple `char*`?

Comment: And dont cast from `void*`, you dont have to.

Comment: You dont do something like this: `memcpy((paquete + puntero),&length,sizeof(int));` and transmitting over the net: `int` might have a different size in the receiving machine. And byte order might mess up things.

Comment: And at least in the code above, you dont read the two `int`s before trying to extract the string, do you? And if you read `length` out of the packet, pay attention to my last commend - you might geht garbage...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your src and dst the right way around?
The destination (or target if you prefer) of memory services in C is the first parameter, so:
strcpy(string, buffer)
will copy buffer **into** string. (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm)

**But**: bufferToString2 is being called with buffer as the first parameter (and it's the source in this case).

In the first case, as was pointed out, you can't do arithmetic on a void* because the math is trying to go to the Nth element if you say:
*(x + N)
and if x is 'void' it has no size, and therefore the Nth element isn't meaningful.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I didn't think to follow the convention when I created the function, but I do use strcpy in the right order in bufferToString2: strcpy(string, (char*) (buffer + startPtr));
As I commented earlier, casting buffer before doing pointer arithmetic will still show issues, albeit different ones.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need to cast a `void *` to `char *` *before* doing arithmetic on it. `gcc` lets you get away with adding byte offsets to a `void *`, but it's not standard C.

Comment: ah. you are right... i misread the code. I would agree with Gil's point that you should use memcpy instead of strcpy because you can't assume the buffer is null terminated. recv just gets a buffer (at least in POSIX). I think the lack of NULL terminated stream is your most likely culprit

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not an answer yet that eventually solved the problem ostensibly, and no further progress on this question, I will summarize what I partially mentioned in my comments to at least provide hints where to start looking for the problem:

A lot of information is, unfortunately, missing to seriously treat this question.

For example, which kind of socket do you use to send / receive your messages?
Is it a pipe, or a network socket - which kind of transport do you use then?

How do you ensure that you received the entire message?
You should at least check the return value of `recv` (which happens to be the number of received octets) and check with the expected length if there is one.

When having received your message,have the message dumped as is - if you are not familiar with using a debugger, a function like this would do as a starter:

```
void dump(const char* buffer, size_t length) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%x", buffer[i] & 0xff);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and invoke it in your code after the `ssize_t received = recv(...)` like `dump(buffer,  received)`.

Furthermore, you don't provide the way you calculate `msgSize` in your first code snippet - how do you guarantee that the string in `mensaje` you pass over to `serializePacket` is not longer than `msgSize` ?

Then, in `serializePacket`, you create a buffer filled like this:

`|  codigo (int) | length (int) |  mensaje ( = terminal zero) |`

but what you read back at the other end is just a c string - you ought to read the 2 ints as well, ought you not?

Then, there is another problem with this bit of serialization: Even if you read back the 2 ints, you would have a piece of code that is entirely unportable and works only if both sender and receiver run on an architecture that represent `int`s precisely the same way and in the same bit order. if you run the sender on a 32 bit system and the receiver on a 64 bit system, you write 4 byte integers, while attempt to read back 8 byte integers. Better use 
types with precisely defined width (like `uint32_t` from [`inttypes.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) ) and explicitly convert to/from network byte order using e.g. [`ntohl(3)` / `htonl(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl).

Lastly, I want to add some remarks to improve the quality of code, that might prevent a lot of potential errors:

Take as example your `bufferToString`:

1. You passed in `string` as `char**` - why?
2. Use appropriate data types - don't use a signed `int` where you deal with non-negative sizes - use the standard type `size_t` instead
3. Don't use `void*` as type unless really necessary - you loose a hell lot of compile time error checking. C automatically converts from `void*` in assignments. So declaring `buffer` as `char*` is highly suggested.

This function, e.g. can harshly be simplified:

```
size_t bufferToString(const char* buffer, char* string, size_t offset) {
    for(size_t i = offset; 0 != buffer[i]; ++i) {
        string[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    return ++i;
}
```

I can only emphazise that network code tends to be hard to debug - there are all kinds of external error sources you cannot really oversee.

Hopefully these hints help to track down the root cause of your problem.